# python deregister weakreference callback

Tags: python, callback, weak-references

How to deregister a callback passed to a weakref.ref() ?

I'm implementing a signal slot module, then I need to be notified when either the object or the method is garbage collected. So I registered a callback for both, that works well. However, after one has been collected, and the signal cleaned, when the second is collected too it still calls the callback.

I can simply ignore this call but it would be much cleaner to be able to prevent it...

Comment: AFAIK the `weakref` module doesn't provide any API to avoid this. The only solution would be to use a [`weakref.finalizer`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize) instead of a normal weak reference and then you can call the [`detach()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize.detach) method.

Comment: @Bakuriu Eventually you should elaborate a little bit more and post that as an answer ;)